# Normalizing relation schema

Tags: mysql, database, schema, relation

My teachers asked me this, and I am having much trouble finding the answer if someone can just explain it to me i would be grateful.
Question:
1NF Relation Schema:
R(**A,B**,C,D,E,F,G)
`fd1: (A,B) -> C, D, E, F, G`

```
fd2: B -> C  
fd3: D -> E  
fd4: F -> B
```

The question is: Normalize the relation R into a set of 2NF relations. Show the primary keys.
Ok I know I must know it alone but this is the first time i see such a form of !NF relation schema please help/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Hello Susan,
Yeah I have read the article and I know about it. But the form my teacher is displaying the data with, is the thing that I am not understanding. So I need one example in front of me and then I can figure out the rest. And this is the first example.